# What is the tenant URL for Default Directory on Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect my app to my Azure Active Directory.

I just followed an example where if the directory name on Azure is myazuredirectory, the tenant URL is myazuredirectory.onmicrosoft.com

What would it be for the "Default Directory"?

Answer (score 1):

A directory has a display name and a domain name (aka tenant URL).  When you create an Azure subscription you automatically get a directory with a display name of "Default Directory".  By default the domain name is usually based on the name under which the subscription is created.

To see what the domain is for your directory, go to the [Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com), select your directory, and go to the Domains tab.